# Stopping key event bubbling in Safari 4 windows

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events, event-bubbling

In Safari 4 windows, it does not seem possible to stop some key events from bubbling up to the browser in Javascript.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492080/disable-f5-key-in-safari-4) got pounced on for trying to stop <kbd>F5</kbd> (a dubious design goal), but the technical problem remains... how do you stop certain key events from bubbling up in Safari 4?  For example,

You can stop:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

You cannot stop:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: PPK seems to be able to cancel up/down keys: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html (see example at bottom of page). Tried safari 4 windows and the document does not scroll. Perhaps you are asking about Function keys? I.e. F1, F2, F3 ... ?

Comment: Good point.  I was trying to stop CTRL+F, etc (so that different behavior can be implemented in flash). Hmm.

Comment: edited question to include more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. My tests gave the same results as yours: I couldn't find a way to prevent the default action of CTRL+F in Safari 4 in Windows, which suggests it's a deliberate design decision. However, I did discover the probably useless fact that putting an alert in my `keydown` event handler prevented the search bar from appearing, regardless of whether I then cancelled the event default action.