# prevent default 'F1' event in iE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

When the user press <kbd>F1</kbd> key,I am planning to display our application help and suppress default action.
I tried with different options not to show help popup of IE.
Here is my Code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.key === 'F1' || e.keyCode == 112) {

                   e.cancelBubble = true;
                    e.cancelable = true;
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.returnValue = false;

                //my help menu code goes here
            }
});
```

Please let me know how can i achieve in showing the help page of my application instead of IE help. 
I am using IE11 version.

Comment: Have you tried `event.originalEvent.keyCode = 0;`, According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099932/jquery-prevent-default-action-function-keys-f3-f4-etc) it works in IE8

Comment: I am not able to see  event.originalEvent

Comment: IE11: event.originalEvent => undefined

Answer (score 6):

You could subscribe to the `window.onhelp` event:

```
window.onhelp =function() { 
    alert();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the support.I am not bale to see onhelp() on window.

Comment: I tried with the above code,but not able to achieve

Comment: please post your entire js

Comment: Here is my js Code:                                                                                                             function showNMCHelp()
  {
      var dialog = NMCApp.addDialog(helpTitle, 800, 400);
      dialog.load('/' + NMCApp.getVirtualDirectoryName() + helpLink, null, true);
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    
      if (e.key === 'F1' || e.keyCode == 112) {
              e.cancelable = true;
              e.stopPropagation();
              e.preventDefault();
              e.returnValue = false;
              showNMCHelp();
      }
  });

Comment: I have used your code and i removed it before posting,but it is not working

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            removedefaulthelp();
            function removedefaulthelp()
            {
                window.onhelp = function () {
                    return false;
                    alert();
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
                if (e.key === 'F1' || e.keyCode == 112) {
                    removedefaulthelp();
                    e.cancelBubble = true;
                    e.cancelable = true;
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.returnValue = false;
                    //my help menu code goes here
                }
            });
}
</script>
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405412/internet-explorer-or-any-browser-f1-keypress-displays-your-own-help) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I tried your code Seems nothing is working fine in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example similar to [Sukanya's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4506158/sukanya) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29279019/212950), but my solution shows how to extend for the F2-F12 keys, and purposely disregards *F-combination keys*, such a CTRL + F1.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Note:  reference your own JQuery library here -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>F-key trap example</h1>
    <div><h2>Example:  Press the 'F1' key to open help</h2></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //uncomment to prevent on startup
        //removeDefaultFunction();          
        /** Prevents the default function such as the help pop-up **/
        function removeDefaultFunction()
        {
            window.onhelp = function () { return false; }
        }
        /** use keydown event and trap only the F-key, 
            but not combinations with SHIFT/CTRL/ALT **/
        $(window).bind('keydown', function(e) {
            //This is the F1 key code, but NOT with SHIFT/CTRL/ALT
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if((keyCode == 112 || e.key == 'F1') && 
                    !(event.altKey ||event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey || event.metaKey))
             {
                // prevent code starts here:
                removeDefaultFunction();
                e.cancelable = true;
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = false;
                // Open help window here instead of alert
                alert('F1 Help key opened, ' + keyCode);
                }
            // Add other F-keys here:
            else if((keyCode == 113 || e.key == 'F2') && 
                    !(event.altKey ||event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey || event.metaKey))
             {
                // prevent code starts here:
                removeDefaultFunction();
                e.cancelable = true;
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = false;
                // Do something else for F2
                alert('F2 key opened, ' + keyCode);
                }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```