# Disable specific function key using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript-framework

I want to disable `F8` key on my web page. Is there any way I can disable it using jquery or any associated plugins or just javascript??

Thanks in advance... `:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this [Disable F5 key in Safari 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492080/disable-f5-key-in-safari-4)

but using keyCode 119:

```
<script>
var fn = function (e)
{

    if (!e)
        var e = window.event;

    var keycode = e.keyCode;
    if (e.which)
        keycode = e.which;

    var src = e.srcElement;
    if (e.target)
        src = e.target;    

    // 119 = F8
    if (119 == keycode)
    {
    alert('nope')
        // Firefox and other non IE browsers
        if (e.preventDefault)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        // Internet Explorer
        else if (e.keyCode)
        {
            e.keyCode = 0;
            e.returnValue = false;
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
document.onkeypress=document.onkeydown=document.onkeyup=fn
</script>
```

Comment: it worls when i click page.. but not working when i click address bar or i click inside pdf..

Comment: That is correct. PDF will not respond to any javascript changes in the page. A PDF is like a black hole, only accessible by Acrobat or whatever reader you have installed

Comment: yea i got it `:)` .... any way thanks for your support.. let me dig deep into it.. Do you know any browser supported reader other than adobe reader which prevent pdf saving??

Comment: You can disable saving in the PDF itself.

Comment: If you're trying to stop people from copying your PDF there is no way that Javascript will help you.  The PDF is already downloaded and saved on the user's machine (albeit in a temp file) when they view it.  Any semi-power user can just open up his temp files, locate the last downloaded PDF, rename it and send it to all his friends.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 119){
        return false;
    }
});
```

i created a jsfiddle sandbox where you can test it (works):

http://jsfiddle.net/alzclarke/yW6H3/

Answer (score 1):

The following code works on most browser whereas I haven't found any incompatible one yet. Let me know if it doesn't work.

The key is to re-map target event to any other original event of trivial key, i.e., make that Fn key behave as normal key.

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function (evt){ 
    var keycode = (evt.keyCode?evt.keyCode:evt.charCode);
    //alert(keycode);
    switch(keycode){
        case 119: //F8 key on Windows and most browsers
        case 63243:  //F8 key on Mac Safari
            evt.preventDefault();                                 
            //Remapping event
            evt.originalEvent.keyCode = 0;
            return false;
            break;
    }
});
```

Reference on key code and explanation on cross browser issue can be found here:
[quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)